# GIT issue in AIX 6.1

Tags: unix, git, aix, github

I recently installed GIT 1.8.1 on my AIX 6.1 machine and am facing a few issues with it.

Now if I login as root and issue git commands like git --version I get the response as shown :
Code:

```
git version 1.8.1
```

And I have tried creating repositories as root too and it works fine.

Now If I login as just a normal user and if I issue the version command : git --version I am getting the response as :

```
genuser:stud:/students/admin> git --version
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program git because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2) could not be loaded.
        0509-152   Member libiconv.so.2 is not found in archive
```

Now how come its working with root user and not working with normal user.

But If I issue man git command in normal user I'm getting the manual for git but the rest of the commands give the above error.

BTW the file libiconv.so.2 is not present in /usr/lib directory but it still works in root user but not in normal user.

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a `LIBPATH` issue, compare root's `LIBPATH` with the `LIBPATH` of the user you're trying to run `git` as.

Comment: Yes its different.How can I modify the LIBPATH variable of genral users to include the path vaiable of the root user.

Comment: Changed the libpath no effect.Still getting the same error.

Comment: I found a similar thread having the same issue but do not know how to apply the fix suggested https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24838 Any idea how to apply this fix.

Comment: Did not set the LIBPATH properly now it works.Thanks a lot.